# Conditional Logistic Regression, Rare Events and R

Tags: r, regression, logit, fixed-effects-model, clogit

I have a panel data set organized around 35 provincial units, with 110 binary "positive" outcomes in the dependent variable.  This is for about 2600 observations in that data set.  I have a couple questions.  1) Would it even be reasonable to run a logit at the national level, combining each province count?  2) Is it reasonable to try for a fixed-effects model, using condionoanl logit/clogit() in R?  3) Would a rare events model be a better alternative and is it possible to do it with fixed effects in R?

Thanks.

Comment: If I have understood correctly (I may not), doing things at an aggregate level may run the risk of invoking the ecological fallacy, I think.

Comment: Yeah I figure thats not going to work.  I suppose the question is, is there enough variance in the dependence variable to run a conditional logit/logit fixed effects?  Or should I look at relogit, in which case is it possible to do that with panel data in R?

Comment: The variance being: 0.0332221